# File Input from PhoneGap 5.2.0 on iOS9 - No longer works

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Using Build.PhoneGap.Com (cli 5.2.0), I created a simple PhoneGap app with index.html that has [input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"] only.

Until recent iOS9 update, file input on this page worked fine. If you clicked "Choose File", you get the "Take Photo or Video / Choose Existing / Cancel" dialog. After iOS9 update, the "Choose File" is no longer working properly. When clicked, you no longer get the "Take Photo or Video / Choose Existing" dialog, instead, you get the "Cancel" dialog that does not go away until you close the app. Two notes:

- I viewed the same index.html page from Safari and Chrome on iPhone, and everything works fine.
- The same PhoneGap app works fine on an iPhone with iOS8.
- What is causing above bug?
- Is there a fix?

Thank you.

Comment: It's a problem on phonegap build service, notify them. It works if you do local development with cordova. BTW, there was a bug for iOS 8 that made apps crash, if you say it worked fine before they might have fixed it.

Comment: It has been fixed on phonegap build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Nov 2, 2015, iOS 9 is supported by Cordova

Apache Cordova iOS 3.9.2
http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/11/02/cordova-ios-3-9-2.html

It will be a few days before *Phonegap Build* as it integrated.

<s>## 1. No support for iOS9 YET! ##</s>

**PhoneGap Build iOS 9 Support Status**

- Sept 23, 2015
- http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap-build-ios-9-support-status
- Top line: iOS 9 is **NOT** officially supported until Cordova-iOS 4.0.0, which the Cordova team is hard at work on. However some issues can be solved with some simple configuration changes.

> At this point in time, 4 bugs are reported to the Cordova Bug repository. Your issue does not appear in the respository - as of this date.

- 4 bugs - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9684?jql=text%20~%20%22iOS9%22
- 1 bug - https://openradar.appspot.com/22186109

  Regardless, of what you are using, as the forum post states, iOS 9 is not officially supported until Cordova-iOS 4.0.0. This means, if you encouter a bug, you must - create a work around, or wait until it is officially supported, *OR* file a bug report with cordova, *OR* wait until someone else creates a work around.