# PhoneGap app stops working after update to iOS 9 (app reinstall helps)

Tags: ios, cordova, ios9, phonegap-build

We have created an application using PhoneGap Build (compiled with 3.7.0) and uploaded to iTunes Connect.
It is working ok, but if the user updates to iOS 9 when the app is installed, it stops working:
Only splashscreen is shown and then the app immediately closes (no log in "Diagnostics & Usage"). Reinstall (remove+add) solves this issue, but we can hardly ask all the user to reinstall the app.

We tried updating to PhoneGap cli-5.1.1 (Cordova iOS 3.8.0) and pushed the new build. The application updates OK, but the problem still remains.

Any ideas what causes this and/or how this could be solved?

**EDIT**:
Ok.. I know iOS 9 is not officially supported until 4.0.0, but this seems to me somehow different than a simple bug. Reinstall of the app helps, so there has to be some issue with the "cached" application data -- I was hoping there was some way to "force wipe" this during update to fix the issue.

Anyway, thanks for the comments. I guess we'll just have to wait until 4.0.0 is released and hope this will somehow fix the issue.

Comment: This has been a problem for weeks. You should do some research.

Comment: Really? I'm not able to find anything similar to my problem. There are some issues with iOS 9 itself, but our application works OK, it's just the iOS update process that somehow breaks things..

Comment: It is not *somehow*, but general laziness. Best of Luck

Comment: search: phonegap update ios9 not **GETS:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846039/file-input-from-phonegap-5-2-0-on-ios9-no-longer-works

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I edited the original post with some more explanation, but it seems like we will have to wait for 4.0.0 and hope it somehow fixes this.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, I read most of the cordova questions and this is the first one that says that an update broke the app but uninstalling and reinstalling fix the issue. The answer you link doesn't point to any issue open like this. His app works fine on iOS 9, but updating from an older version breaks the app.

Comment: @jcesarmobile, If I knew all the reason and ways that iOS9 has broken apps, I would be making money on that right now. The OP states, in short, "if the user updates to iOS9 and the app is installed, the app crashes. If they install and reinstall, it works.".  I doubt anyone knows, or will ever know why this is happening. It could be an iOS9 bug that does not clear the cache properly. Maybe rebooting after installing iOS9 fixes it. I do nott know - I have NOT upgraded to iOS9. My device is still 8.4

Comment: then don't say "***This*** has been a problem for weeks"

Comment: They did not say state any temporal references clearly. BUT to be very clear on this. I AM NOT STATING I know the issue. I am simple stating (in an indirect manner) to the OP that iOS9 is not currently supported by Cordova. It is up to that person to make the critical judgement.